# X and X→Y are not in 1-1 correspondence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would solve the exercize 1.5 of [The Formal Semantics of Programming Languages](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/formal-semantics-programming-languages) book:

> Show for any sets X and Y, with Y containing at least two elements, that there cannot be a 1-1 correspondence between X and the set of functions (X→Y).

I suppose that it should be proof by absurd, but I don't find nothing of absurd considering infinite sets!

Have you any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the size of the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ in the case where $Y$ has two elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on the famous [Cantor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem) that the size of the set of all subsets of a set is larger than the size of the set.

Choose one of the elements of $Y$ to represent "IS A MEMBER" and another one to represent "IS NOT A MEMBER". Then for each subset of $X$ choose a function that assigns to each element of $X$ the appropriate one of those two elements of $Y$. I.e. for $x\in X$ let $f(x)=y_1$ if $x$ is a member of the subset, and $f(x)=y_2$ if it is not a member of the subset.

We have just shown that the functions from $X$ to $Y$ are at least as numerous as the subsets of $X$, which are in turn more numerous than $X$.

That argument of mine works if you can use Cantor's Theorem. If not, look at the proof of Cantor's theorem and you can modify it to prove your problem.